# Prove $\sqrt{\frac{a+3}{a+3b}}+\sqrt{\frac{b+3}{b+3c}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+3}{c+3a}} \ge 3$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c$ are positives such that $ab+bc+ca=3$. Prove that:
$$\sqrt{\frac{a+3}{a+3b}}+\sqrt{\frac{b+3}{b+3c}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+3}{c+3a}} \ge 3$$
Once, I see this problem in AoPS:https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h3248614p29942459

I thought it was easy until I decide to solve it. Here is some of my attempt:

**First attempt**:
By using AM-GM, we have:
$$\sqrt{\frac{a+3}{a+3b}}+\sqrt{\frac{b+3}{b+3c}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+3}{c+3a}} \ge 3\sqrt[6]{\frac{(a+3)(b+3)(c+3)}{(a+3b)(b+3c)(c+3a)}}$$
So we just need to prove:
$$(a+3)(b+3)(c+3) \ge (a+3b)(b+3c)(c+3a)$$
Which is obviously wrong.

**Second attempt**:
By Bernoulli inequality, we have:
$$\sqrt{\frac{a+3}{a+3b}} \ge 1+\frac{3(b-1)}{2(a+3b)}$$
So the first inequality is equivalent to:
$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{3(b-1)}{2(a+3b)} \leq 0$$
which is equivalent to:
$$\sum_{cyc }a^2 b + 6 \sum_{cyc}a^2 c+27 a b c \leq 39+3\sum_{cyc}a^2$$
Fortunately, it's obvious, but there is a big mistake here

This is Bernoulli inequality is reversed for $h \le1$, so my second attempt is failed.

Additionally, it's also a proof using Holder by sir arqady, but I and the author want to find a nicer proof for this inequality.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**Some thoughts.**

By Holder inequality, we have
$$\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \sqrt{\frac{a+3}{a+3b}}\right)^2
\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a + 3b)(a + 3)^2(c + 2)^3
\ge \left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a + 3)(c + 2)\right)^3.
$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a + 3)(c + 2)\right)^3 \ge 9 \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a + 3b)(a + 3)^2(c + 2)^3.$$
This inequality is true which is verified by *Mathematica* (a Computer Algebra System).
A human verfiable proof is required.

Comment: Thanks @River Li, it's a nice idea. However, I wanna to find other method to solve this problem, have you think of Isolated Fudging or LM?

Comment: @DanhTrung Usually I don't consider LM for Olympiad type inequalities (I used several times in the past for the problems which are very difficult by other methods). I think some users will do it.